# How to extend the logical space on my System?

Tags: lvm, disk-usage

I have two SSDs,the first one is almost full.This is the lsblk output

```
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                  7:0    0   4,2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/501
loop1                  7:1    0   156M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/91
loop2                  7:2    0 160,8M  1 loop /snap/midori/550
loop3                  7:3    0  42,8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
loop4                  7:4    0  17,9M  1 loop /snap/pdftk/9
loop5                  7:5    0 160,7M  1 loop /snap/midori/451
loop6                  7:6    0 140,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/92
loop7                  7:7    0    89M  1 loop /snap/core/7713
loop8                  7:8    0  54,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1223
loop9                  7:9    0   3,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
loop10                 7:10   0 144,6M  1 loop /snap/postman/96
loop11                 7:11   0  44,2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
loop12                 7:12   0  54,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1192
loop13                 7:13   0  89,1M  1 loop /snap/core/7917
loop14                 7:14   0 132,4M  1 loop /snap/postman/93
loop15                 7:15   0 615,6M  1 loop /snap/intellij-idea-community/177
loop16                 7:16   0   956K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/73
loop17                 7:17   0   4,2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/544
loop18                 7:18   0  14,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/359
loop19                 7:19   0 320,3M  1 loop /snap/datagrip/61
loop20                 7:20   0  14,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/317
loop21                 7:21   0   956K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/81
loop22                 7:22   0   3,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/107
loop23                 7:23   0   618M  1 loop /snap/intellij-idea-community/185
loop24                 7:24   0 140,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/97
loop25                 7:25   0 149,9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/71
loop26                 7:26   0 319,5M  1 loop /snap/datagrip/64
sda                    8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1                 8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2                 8:2    0 465,3G  0 part /
sdb                    8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─volgroup-projects  253:0    0    10G  0 lvm  /mnt/projects
├─volgroup-db        253:1    0    10G  0 lvm  /mnt/db
└─volgroup-workspace 253:2    0 911,5G  0 lvm  /mnt/workspace
sdc                    8:32   0 111,8G  0 disk 
└─sdc1                 8:33   0 111,8G  0 part 
sr0                   11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

How to resize the storage pools? I do not want to reformat my disk, but I do not have enough experience with this. I am on Ubuntu 18.04. What should I do step by step?

```
 vgs

  VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  volgroup   1   3   0 wz--n- 931,51g    0
```

And vgdisplay

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               volgroup
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               931,51 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              238467
  Alloc PE / Size       238467 / 931,51 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               gJe4Qy-Qu8n-dVmd-KDDH-YgHd-c9O2-Wg6vQM

 lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/volgroup/projects
  LV Name                projects
  VG Name                volgroup
  LV UUID                JyAbOT-pN1w-zWwM-aPsO-UPpM-QqTC-0pOzMZ
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time miki, 2019-05-27 13:55:15 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                10,00 GiB
  Current LE             2560
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/volgroup/db
  LV Name                db
  VG Name                volgroup
  LV UUID                SuWPuB-QoTQ-HklW-N9qT-t0zf-AhcX-0YBAFK
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time miki, 2019-05-27 13:55:36 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                10,00 GiB
  Current LE             2560
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/volgroup/workspace
  LV Name                workspace
  VG Name                volgroup
  LV UUID                GwJL1X-6Thi-I8xj-w1iK-mwjS-DJC1-BeSgOh
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time miki, 2019-05-27 13:56:25 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                911,51 GiB
  Current LE             233347
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2
```

df output

```
 df -h
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                            7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                           1,6G  2,3M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/sda2                       457G  424G  9,8G  98% /
tmpfs                           7,8G  387M  7,5G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                           7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1                       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1265
/dev/loop0                      133M  133M     0 100% /snap/postman/93
/dev/loop7                       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/pdftk/9
/dev/loop4                      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/97
/dev/loop2                      161M  161M     0 100% /snap/midori/550
/dev/loop3                       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/7917
/dev/loop8                      1,0M  1,0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop5                      145M  145M     0 100% /snap/postman/96
/dev/loop6                      321M  321M     0 100% /snap/datagrip/61
/dev/loop9                      618M  618M     0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-community/185
/dev/loop10                      43M   43M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
/dev/loop11                     320M  320M     0 100% /snap/datagrip/64
/dev/loop13                     157M  157M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/91
/dev/loop14                     4,3M  4,3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop15                     161M  161M     0 100% /snap/midori/451
/dev/loop12                     1,0M  1,0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/73
/dev/loop16                      45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
/dev/loop17                      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/317
/dev/loop18                      90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8039
/dev/loop19                     4,3M  4,3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/501
/dev/loop20                     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/92
/dev/loop21                     3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/107
/dev/loop22                     150M  150M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/71
/dev/loop23                     616M  616M     0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-community/177
/dev/loop24                     3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
/dev/loop25                      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/359
/dev/loop26                      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1223
/dev/sda1                       511M  6,1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/volgroup-projects   9,8G   37M  9,3G   1% /mnt/projects
/dev/mapper/volgroup-db         9,8G   37M  9,3G   1% /mnt/db
/dev/mapper/volgroup-workspace  897G   77M  851G   1% /mnt/workspace
tmpfs                           1,6G   16K  1,6G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs                           1,6G   40K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lvdisplay`

Comment: I just added,take a look pls.

Comment: You've allocated all of the physical extents in your volume group to the three logical volumes. Where are you going to get the free/unused physical extents to resize the logical volume(s)?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa What should I do?

Comment: Start by adding the output of `df -h` to your question.

Comment: Assuming the filesystems support size reduction, you can shrink one or more of the logical volumes to create free physical extents, which you can then allocate to one or more logical volumes to increase their size. Which logical volumes do you want to shrink and grow? What filesystems are they using?

Comment: /dev/mapper/volgroup-workspace , It uses ext4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of reducing the size of the *workspace* logical volume by 10G, and then increasing the size of the *db* logical volume.

```
lvresize -r -L -10G /dev/mapper/volgroup-workspace
lvresize -r -L +10G /dev/mapper/volgroup-db
```